# PhoneGap Build download mp3 file to sd

Tags: cordova, mp3, file-transfer

i added this code to my config.xml

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
```

i have phonegap.js in my html

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

and here is a code for filetransfer

```
<script>
function foo()
{
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(
    "http://mydomain/music.mp3",
    "file://sdcard/Download/music.mp3",
    function(entry) {
        alert("Sound downloaded!");
    },
    function(error) {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    });
}   
</script>

<span onclick="foo()">Yüklə</span>
```

or `<button onclick="foo()">Download</button>`

Please Help. Thanks. Also i use Phonegap 3.0.0 version

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing?  What is your question?

Comment: nothing happens when i click download